# How to find open ports using netstat?

Tags: linux, networking, port, nmap, netstat

When I do a `netstat -tuln`, I get the following output

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:9390            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::4444                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

I see *22, 25, 4444, 6379* and *9390* ports. How many of them are listening to external machines?

What does `Local Address` in the above results tell us? `127.0.0.1` is localhost, so is it only reachable from the machine itself? Does `0.0.0.0` mean it is reachable from any interface?

I just want to find which ports are reachable from remote machines, for example, `nmap -p-` from an external machine, it just returns *22* port

```
Not shown: 65534 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh
```

How to get such information from netstat/ss? I basically want to find the ports which can listen to other machines without using `nmap` from an external machine.

Answer (score 0):

> What does Local Address in the above results tell us? 127.0.0.1 is
>   localhost, so is it only reachable from the machine itself? Does
>   0.0.0.0 mean it is reachable from any interface?

Your assumption is correct. 0.0.0.0 basically means any IP address on your machine = all the configured network interfaces. 127.0.0.1 = the loopback interface.

> I just want to find which ports are reachable from remote machines,
>   for example, nmap -p- from an external machine, it just returns 22
>   port

By default nmap scans only the 1000 most popular ports. Add this: `-p 0-65535` or: `-p-`. Then it should detect port 9390 as open too.

Comment: I have `-p-` itself, ```Host is up (0.00026s latency).
Not shown: 65534 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
22/tcp open  ssh```

Comment: Detecting open ports is not always clear-cut. Perhaps nmap didn't get an expected response and wrongly reported the port as closed. I would try `-sV` to force nmap to do more probes against the port. Adding the `-p` option to netstat should show you the program using the port: `netstat -tulnp`. The Internet says it's a default port for Openvas (?)

Comment: Yes 9390 is being used by Openvas

Comment: Are you scanning from the machine itself or from another host ? I see at least two possibilities: 1) OpenVAS decided not to respond to the probe 2) check your firewall rules - OpenVAS may be listening to the port but may not receive anything because the firewall won't let the requests through.

Comment: ```Chain IN_public_allow (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW,UNTRACKED```

Comment: If the default rule in your `iptables` configuration is to allow only what is explicitly allowed and deny everything else, then that makes sense. If this is the only rule in your ACCEPT chain it is normal that you're only seeing port 22 as open. The firewall is filtering all other ports.

Comment: So my question, can't we extract this information using netstat itself? What are the tools which which I can find the ports open? Running Nmap from an external computer is an option, but I want a command to run internally itself.

Comment: Then `netstat` is your best bet. I would add the `-l` option just to be sure ([`-l, --listening`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/eoan/en/man8/netstat.8.html)).
But your question is twofold: "I just want to find which ports are reachable from remote machines. `netstat` will show you the listening ports on the local machine but that *does not mean they are reachable from remote machines*, since `iptables` may filter them. And some ports are only bound to the loopback interface (127.0.0.1), thus they are not reachable from remote machines either.